# "raise" followed by conditional statement (python)

Tags: python, conditional-statements, python-2.5, raise

I'm trying to understand some python 2.5 code and I came across this pattern:

```
def __init__(self, matrix, top_buttons, side_buttons, config_button):
        raise isinstance(matrix, ButtonMatrixElement) or AssertionError
        raise matrix.width() == 8 and matrix.height() == 8 or AssertionError
        raise isinstance(top_buttons, tuple) or AssertionError
        raise len(top_buttons) == 8 or AssertionError
        raise isinstance(side_buttons, tuple) or AssertionError
        raise len(side_buttons) == 8 or AssertionError
        raise isinstance(config_button, ButtonElement) or AssertionError
```

I tried testing this out in the shell with some simple conditional statements like this:

```
>>> str = 'hello'
>>> raise len(str) == 5 or AssertionError

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    raise len(str) == 5 or AssertionError
TypeError: exceptions must be classes, instances, or strings (deprecated), not bool
```

So judging from this test, at least the way I tried it, you can't raise a boolean statement.  What does it mean to raise a conditional expression then and why does it work in the `__init__` function but not in my test code?

Comment: That pattern makes **no sense** whatsoever.

Comment: The only way to use a conditional when `raise`-ing would be e.g. `raise SomeError if condition else AnotherError`, but that seems needlessly confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code is nonsense, a botched attempt at something that looks like an [`assert` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) that fails, as you have discovered.

What they *should* have written is:

```
assert isinstance(matrix, ButtonMatrixElement)
```

etcetera.

It appears you found [decompiled Ableton Live scripts](http://julienbayle.net/ableton-live-9-midi-remote-scripts/), but the *decompilation script produced wrong Python code*. The bytecode for an `assert` looks like this (Python 2.5 bytecode):

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compile('''assert isinstance(matrix, ButtonMatrixElement)''', '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (isinstance)
              3 LOAD_NAME                1 (matrix)
              6 LOAD_NAME                2 (ButtonMatrixElement)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 JUMP_IF_TRUE             7 (to 22)
             15 POP_TOP             
             16 LOAD_GLOBAL              3 (AssertionError)
             19 RAISE_VARARGS            1
        >>   22 POP_TOP             
             23 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             26 RETURN_VALUE
```

and it looks as if whatever automated process was used to decompile the bytecode translated that to the code you see rather than recognise that as an `assert`.

Note however that if the `isinstance()` call returns `True`, the jump instruction (index 12, `JUMP_IF_TRUE`) jumps *past* the `RAISE_VARARGS` instruction, while the re-constructed code doesn't. Compare this to an actual `raise ... or ...` statement, you'll notice the jump doesn't go past the `raise`:

```
>>> dis.dis(compile('raise foo or bar', '<stdin>', 'exec'))
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (foo)
              3 JUMP_IF_TRUE             4 (to 10)
              6 POP_TOP             
              7 LOAD_NAME                1 (bar)
        >>   10 RAISE_VARARGS            1
             13 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

Presumably the code generator was just not sophisticated to handle this; if you assume only `or` generates `JUMP_IF_TRUE` and don't handle the offsets properly, you can see how the error was made.

Comment: Is it possible the author of that code could have redefined how the `raise` keyword operates?  The only reason I have some doubt is that this program does actually work.  If this is an error and there's no chance there's some weird, confusing code-style going on, is it possible this program would still run, and that this is an error that wouldn't halt execution?

Comment: How certain are you that that code is actually being executed? Because you can't redefine `raise` without patching the interpreter C code and recompiling.

Comment: If this code were to actually run and *nothing caught the exception* the program would actually halt, yes.

Comment: It's code for a midi control surface script in Ableton Live (completely legal to edit by the way).  I know the script works, but I have no idea if that specific part is working.

Comment: @zoogleflatt: ah! Those scripts were reverse-engineered from bytecode and *the reverse engineering is **wrong***.

Comment: oh wow... you're probably right.  You think it interpreted assert statements as raise's in the reverse engineering then?  I'm new to python, I didn't know how accurate the reverse engineering is.

Comment: @zoogleflatt: you have to translate bytecode back to Python syntax, and that translation went awry here.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been answered before, this is a bug in the decompiler that has been used in the process of reverse engineering the python byte code. If you'd like to decompile the files on your own, you can use the following version of the script:

https://github.com/frankebersoll/uncompyle2

The aforementioned bug should be fixed there. When you decompile `MainSelectorComponent.pyc` with this version, you get:

```
class MainSelectorComponent(ModeSelectorComponent):
    """ Class that reassigns the button on the launchpad to different functions """

    def __init__(self, matrix, top_buttons, side_buttons, config_button):
        assert isinstance(matrix, ButtonMatrixElement)
        assert matrix.width() == 8 and matrix.height() == 8
        assert isinstance(top_buttons, tuple)
        assert len(top_buttons) == 8
        assert isinstance(side_buttons, tuple)
        assert len(side_buttons) == 8
        assert isinstance(config_button, ButtonElement)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Just used this with the Push control scripts.